# Facebook api, business_management is invalid scope? Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently added business_management to our list of application scopes.  Now when I go through the auth process I get the following error.

> Invalid Scopes: business_management. This message is only shown to
>   developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if
>   present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I can't find anywhere any answers why this would be an invalid scope.  I assume it's like manage_pages, but are there different requirements or is the auth url different?

Comment: `business_management` was introduced with API v2.7, so you need to specify at least that version in your login dialog call (if your app was created before v2.7 was introduced, otherwise that would be the lowest API version it could use anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to your app not having been reviewed and approved for the required permissions. I would advise checking at the URL below:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[[appid]]/review-status/

And check if the required permissions have been reviewed and granted.

If they have not, you will continue seeing the above error.